# Split an integer into bytes and combine back into the integers results into error

Tags: c++

Toy program to split an integer into 4 bytes and later combine these bytes to get back the input value results into error. However the program works for positive integers. I am interested in signed integers. Need help.

Expected Output: -12345

Actual Output: -57

```
int main()
{
    int j,i = -12345;

    char b[4];
    b[0] = (i >> 24) & 0xFF;
    b[1] = (i >> 16) & 0xFF;
    b[2] = (i >> 8) & 0xFF;
    b[3] = (i >> 0) & 0xFF;

    j = (int)((b[0] << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8) | (b[3] << 0));

    std::cout << j;
    
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Right-shifting a signed integer is implementation-defined ([before C++20](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#3)). Don't do it if you want to stay portable. You could use `memcpy` instead. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/zoGEze)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Agree. Edited - removing the char casting lets the positive input value to work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Thanks. Will it work in C also?

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately, I'm a bit rusty when it comes to C, but `memcpy` should be safe there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually *two* problems that leads to your "error".

The first is that the result of e.g. `b[0] << 24` will be an `int`. When you cast that to a `char` (and assuming that `char` is an 8-bit type) then you cut off the top 24 bits of the value, truncating it.

The second problem is that `char` could be *unsigned* (it's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned). If `char` is unsigned then the value `-1` (`0xffffffff`) will become `255` (`0x000000ff`).

When you then bring all that together it will almost certainly result in wrong values.

In general, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like in `(char)(b[0] << 24)`) when programming in C++, you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

---

One possible way to solve your problem, always work with explicit unsigned data-types.

First you need to copy the original `int` value to an `unsigned int`:

```
unsigned ui;
memcpy(&ui, &i, sizeof ui);
```

Then use `ui` instead of `i` when doing the "split". And explicitly use `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char b[sizeof(unsigned)] = { 0 };
b[0] = (ui >> 24) & 0xFF;
b[1] = (ui >> 16) & 0xFF;
b[2] = (ui >> 8) & 0xFF;
b[3] = (ui >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

Then to put it all back, again use an explicit unsigned type, and copy it to the resulting variable:

```
unsigned uj = (b[0] << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8) | (b[3] << 0);
memcpy(&j, &uj, sizeof j);
```

I suggest using unsigned data types here to avoid possible problems that can come from sign-extension during conversion.

Comment: How to use as signed char?

Comment: @ark1974 Be explicit: `signed char b[sizeof(int)];`

Comment: Is it actually defined behavior to `memcpy` an `int` into an `unsigned` and then to read from that `unsigned`? I fully understand why it will (probably) work, but I was under the impression that copying to anything but a `char`(based) buffer and to read the value would be UB.

Comment: Good explaination +1. Works after putting paranthesis with `sizeof()` and replacing `unsigned uj` with `unsigned int uj`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works only for possessive numbers! "i" is negative and by shifting it to to right b[0] becomes positive! and finally desensitization results error!

try

```
int main()
{
    int j, i = -12345;

    const char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i);
    j = *reinterpret_cast<const int*>(bytes);


    std::cout << j;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you really mean `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, you are right! but unexpectedly the previous code works fine in c++ 14!! any way i changed it to meet definitions!